# Oracle APEX session and application timing out

Tags: oracle-apex

For 2 days now, my APEX is timing out every 10 minutes or less and it makes me lose my work!

I've tried to clean browser cookies and all...

Comment: Can you share more info?

Answer (score 0):

*Timeout* is set in application's **Shared components**, Security Attributes, **Session Management** section.

"Maximum Session Length" is measured in seconds. If unset, it defaults to 43200 seconds (which is 12 hours) (for Apex 19.1) so ... check what it is currently set to.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried another browser/computer and the problem didn't happen. Maybe my Chrome is acting up and that's not APEX fault...

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are facing is that your killing your previous sessions.

Every time you log in on an APEX application, it generates a session for your user (it's the random numbers in your URL)

[image]

If you have another browser tab opened and you request another log-in on the application, then another session is generated and if you go back to the other tab and try anything there, you will be asked to log-in again and if you do, the other session that you just logged-in will be killed.

For each application you log-in, is generated a session id that is saved on cookies of your browser. So just make sure that there's no other window or tab opened of that application already on the same session of your browser (although you can use different browser or incognito mode).

Also, pay attention in any favorite links that you made that links an APEX application. The same thing will happen if you are already logged-in and click on the favorite link that has a session on its URL.

This all can be avoided if you configure "Rejoin Sessions" parameter on the APEX installation enviroment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39151/adm_wrkspc002.htm#BABJCGAG

Comment: Thank you very much, Higor. That should probably be it. My browser had opened all tabs from the day before and I always have a bunch of tabs opened and the problem was over once I close them, restart the computer and start APEX from one tab only, then opening other tabs.